# Placing image byte array to a session does not render in <img src> tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, image

I have an image converted to base 64 using an online tool. If I copy and paste it in my `<img src=data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk....">`, in the view, I am able to see the image. But since I want this image to be available on all my views, I placed this "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk...." to a session variable as so:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["user_image"] = "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSk...."
```

When I try to retrieve it in my view using this code:

```
<div>
    Hello @HttpContext.Current.Session["user_name"]. Your id is @HttpContext.Current.Session["user_id"]
    @{
            var imageBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String((byte[]) HttpContext.Current.Session["user_image"]);
            var imageSrc = string.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", imageBase64);
     }
    <img alt="programmer.jpg" src="@imageSrc " />
</div>
```

I cannot get the image to render. Can you please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The string you set to session is already in the base 64 image source format ( with the `data:image/jpeg;base64,` prefix). In your view, you are trying to cast it to a byte array , which will throw an **invalid cast exception** when you execute the view code.

Simply use the string value from session

```
@{
    var imageBase64 = HttpContext.Current.Session["user_image"];
    <img alt="programmer.jpg" src="@imageBase64"/>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who are curious, this is how I did it. In my view:

```
<img alt="programmer.jpg"
         src="@HttpContext.Current.Session["user_image"]" />
```